# Write to an S3 bucket using Stitch Functions

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

In MongoDB Atlas, I want to set a trigger such that whenever I Insert a record to a specific collection (e.g.: testCollection) it writes "Hello" to an S3 bucket.

I was able to set a trigger successfully to invoke a Stitch function. However, this function could not write to S3 bucket. Is there any proper documentation I can refer, or any help I can get?

BTW, I tried,

```
exports = function() {
    const s3 = context.services.get("aws").s3('us-west-2');
    return s3.PutObject({
       "Body": "Hello world!",
       "ContentType": "text/plain",
       "ACL": "public-read",
       "Bucket": "my-bucket-name",
       "Key": "test-object"
    });
};
```

example in the documentation. It does not work or I am missing something.
I logged `const s3 = context.services.get("aws")` and what it prints in the log is `undefined`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you run the function in the debug console? Make sure that you have a rule for s3 that allows you to perform the PutObject action.